# Virtualhost Document Root changing web root for entire server

Tags: linux, apache, centos, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I currently have example.com pointing to Server one. I wanted to server example.com from a different directory  ( `/WebData` )

I did this by editing `httpd.conf`

```
http://pastebin.com/UjHhRNTX
```

I this works as desired.

I then found out I needed to add website.org to the server. So I mounted another disk and created a dir called `/WebDataWebsite`

and created `/etc/httpd/conf.d/websiteorg.conf` with the following VHost:

http://pastebin.com/GTmqtABf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/WebDataWebsite"
       ServerName website.org
       ServerAlias www.website.org
       <Directory "/WebDataWebsite">
               Require all granted
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For some reason all traffic to example.com and website.org were both directed to `index.htm` in `/WebDataWebsite`

What I am doing wrong? How to I make `/WebData` (in `httpd.conf`) the default website but filter by servername website.org with the VHost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use Alias's for the second site. Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

It's unlikely that second declaration of the VH is being picked up by apache as it can not deal with two declarations of the same I believe.

Comment: Something along the lines of Alias www.website.org /WebDataSite

Comment: Thanks, I ended up moving the first site to a VirtualHost so both sites were virtual hosts. From experience I noticed the first virtual host takes all connections not specified specifically in other virtual hosts. this resolved my problem